# How to install Yii2 framework - advanced template on shared hosting?

Tags: yii2, shared-hosting, yii2-advanced-app

I've tried to download and install the framework but it doesn't have a index file in `frontend\web` directory.

What i have to do to start using the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install it locally and run init to generate the missing files, like described [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md). After that just upload the application to the shared host through FTP.

Also, [Yii2 Practical-A App](http://demos.krajee.com/app-practical-a) might be useful to you.